# Update UI (activityIndicator) in dispatch_sync queue (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

This is my **Sign In** button :

```
- (IBAction)signInButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.phoneNumberTextField.text length] == 0 || [self.passwordTextField.text length] == 0) {
        [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Alert!" withMessage:kEmptyTextFieldAlertMSG withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];

    } else {
        if ([self alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber] == YES) {
            if ([self.password isEqualToString:self.passwordTextField.text]) {
                [self goToHomeViewController];

            } else {
                [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Wrong Password!" withMessage:kWrongPasswordMSG withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];

            }

        } else {
            [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Alert!" withMessage:kSignInPhoneNumberDoesnotExistMSG withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my **alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber** method, where I am just checking if the given phone number is registered or not.

```
- (BOOL)alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    __block BOOL isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = NO;

    BlockWeakSelf weakSelf = self;
    SignInViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("mySyncQueue", NULL), ^{
        NSString *PhoneNumberWithIsoCountryCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", strongSelf.countryCode, strongSelf.phoneNumberTextField.text];
        strongSelf.userModelClass = [[RetrieveDataClass class] retrieveUserInfoForPhoneNumber:PhoneNumberWithIsoCountryCode];
        if ([strongSelf.userModelClass.phone_number length] != 0) {
            strongSelf.phoneNumber = strongSelf.userModelClass.phone_number;
            strongSelf.password = strongSelf.userModelClass.password;
            isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = YES;
            [strongSelf.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }
    });

    return isThisPhoneNumberRegistered;
}
```

With this method the problem is that the `activityIndicator` is not appearing when I press **Sign In** button. Otherwise it works synchronize way, which is perfect.

The reason `activityIndicator` is not appearing is that I have to update UI related change in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` (Or not??). But If I rearrange my code like this :

```
- (BOOL)alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    __block BOOL isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = NO;

    BlockWeakSelf weakSelf = self;
    SignInViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("mySyncQueue", NULL), ^{
            NSString *PhoneNumberWithIsoCountryCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", strongSelf.countryCode, strongSelf.phoneNumberTextField.text];
            strongSelf.userModelClass = [[RetrieveDataClass class] retrieveUserInfoForPhoneNumber:PhoneNumberWithIsoCountryCode];
            if ([strongSelf.userModelClass.phone_number length] != 0) {
                strongSelf.phoneNumber = strongSelf.userModelClass.phone_number;
                strongSelf.password = strongSelf.userModelClass.password;
                isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = YES;
                [strongSelf.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            }
        });
    });

    return isThisPhoneNumberRegistered;
}
```

The `activityIndicator` is showing perfectly, but it always return `isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = NO`, because it works asynchronize way, where my update `isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = YES` return lately.

So If I want, this scenario where:

1. User press **Sign In** button
2. Then the `activityIndicator` shows up
3. My server call (`strongSelf.userModelClass = [[RetrieveDataClass class] retrieveUserInfoForPhoneNumber:PhoneNumberWithIsoCountryCode];`) retrieve data and set `isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = YES` or `isThisPhoneNumberRegistered = NO` according to it
4. Then return the value to `If else` condition

   ```
   if ([self alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber] == YES) {
           if ([self.password isEqualToString:self.passwordTextField.text]) {
               [self goToHomeViewController];

   } else {
               [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Wrong Password!" withMessage:kWrongPasswordMSG withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];

   }
   ```

How can I do it?
A lot of Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need any queue or activity-indicator within the `alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber`-method? As far as I can see all these code is called withing the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you *want* to use Asynch processes so you can "do other stuff" such as updating the UI to let the user know something is going on.

In order to do that, you need to separate your logic. Try to think of it in these terms:

```
signInButtonAction {
   if no phone or password entered
      show alert
   else
      showAnimatedSpinner()
      checkForRegisteredPhone()
}

checkForRegisteredPhone {
   // start your async check phone number process
   //  on return from the async call,
   if !registered
      hide spinner
      show kSignInPhoneNumberDoesnotExistMSG message
   else
      checkForMatchingPassword()
}

checkForMatchingPassword {
   if !passwordsMatch
      hide spinner
      show "passwords don't match" message
   else
      hide spinner
      goToHomeViewController
}
```

In other words, don't write your code so it gets "locked into" a process, preventing anything else from happening.

Comment: All I need is to call two separate method in `dispatch_asyn` response. With my `BOOL isThisPhoneNumberRegistered` can't be done, I guess. It's working now. Thanks mate.